# ConcurrentHashMap and Hash table difference

Tags: java, multithreading

I am new to Java and stackoverflow and am seeking answer from experienced folks, who have worked on Collections Framework.

I read that hashTable is thread safe and so is concurrentHashMap, but a concurrentHashMap is faster than a hashTable, since it gives lock on segments of the map to the accessing threads.

How does this work internally? How is the size of segment decided? Example: if there are 40 entries in concurrentHashMap, and 3 threads trying to retrieve/modify data, how will the segments be decided?

Any images/explanations/code on this would be really awesome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: basically ConcurrentHashMap have better performance because implemented using CAS operations instead of locking which causes many context switches and waits.

Comment: This is an excellent article on ConcurrentHashMap: http://www.burnison.ca/articles/the-concurrency-of-concurrenthashmap

Comment: Thank you, this really helps. Not sure why it is marked duplicate since the other question is "Difference between HashMap and HashTable"